# Preferred JavaScript mode for emacs? Is it js2-mode from Yegge?

Tags: javascript, emacs

There are a couple JavaScript modes out there:

- [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/) by Steve Yegge
- [javascript.el](http://www.brgeight.se/downloads/emacs/javascript.el) by Karl Landström.
- espresso?
- Something else?

Does anyone have a recommendation on which to use?

---

**EDIT**
2011 June 11 - This is sort of an old, outdated question at this point. FYI: Emacs v23 now includes a javascript mode, it's called js-mode and it is basically a renamed and updated espresso mode.  I've chosen to use the built-in mode.

Comment: I've been using a [js2-mode fork](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode) that has decent community backing/support in fixing things. The fixes made me switch back to js2-mode using, instead of js-mode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's also [espresso-mode](http://www.nongnu.org/espresso/).

A note from the espresso-mode homepage:

> Espresso has been incorporated into GNU Emacs starting with version 23.2 and has been renamed js-mode.

Comment: +1 espresso-mode is much better for navigating around functions (`C-M-a` and `C-M-e`) than js2-mode. The author also actively responds to issue requests unlike js2-mode

Comment: Good to know.  I was ready to pull the trigger on js2-mode but now I have to rethink it.

Comment: js-mode (formerly expresso) doesn't handle etags very well, even when used with exuberant-ctags. It chokes on namespaced functions. e.g. typing ```M-.``` on ```this.myFunction()``` would look for ```.myFunction``` instead of ```myFunction```. It also would only look at files open in other buffers instead of everything indexed in TAGS. Check out mooz's community fork of js2-mode, which is actively maintained. https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode/

Answer (score 6):

I use js2-mode for JavaScript authoring, and it's excellent. It's not ideal for JavaScript-like languages, though (ActionScript), so it's good to have a simple mode around as a backup for those cases.

Comment: So JavaScript is not "JavaScript-like"? Do you mean to say "non-JavaScript languages that are similar to JavaScript"?

Comment: Conway, everyone else understood what mr unknown was saying. give him a break.

Comment: js2-mode already included into GNU Emacs tree, and will released as part of GNU Emacs 23.2

Comment: @Alex, you mean espresso-mode.  The js2-mode (by Steve Yegge) is _not_ being included into Emacs.  They included espresso-mode, and renamed it js-mode.